# get edittext value which present outside the listview, get edittext value inside OnItemClick

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am new to android apps development,

I want to get edittext value which present outside the listview, and I want to get value inside OnItemClick. when user enter text and click list item I need to get both list item selected and edittext text value.

I Created main layout containing one edittext and listview. I want to get edittext value in listview OnItemClick event.

I tried I can't get it. Please guide me.

Here I list out my sample program.

MainActivity.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ArrayList<String> listVal = new ArrayList<String>();
    public EditText searchKey;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        searchKey = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchKey);
        ListView spinner = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        listVal.add("Apple");
        listVal.add("Avocado");
        listVal.add("Banana");
        listVal.add("Blueberry");
        listVal.add("Coconut");
        listVal.add("Durian");
        listVal.add("Guava");
        listVal.add("Kiwifruit");
        listVal.add("Jackfruit");
        ListAdapter listAdapter = new ListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list, listVal);
        spinner.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        spinner.setOnItemClickListener(listAdapter);
    }
}
```

ListAdapter.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements OnItemClickListener {

    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<String> values;
    int layoutResourceId;
    public ListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<String> values) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.values = values;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.listItem);
            textView.setText(values.get(position));
            return rowView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        TextView message = (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.listItem);
        Toast.makeText(context, message.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchKey"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:ems="10" >
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/searchKey"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="15dip"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: u can take setOnItemClickListener in MainActivity

Comment: Thanks for reply tsp. I tried but I need like that way...If not possible I will change my program to your guidelines. Once again thanks tsp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
        public class MainActivity extends Activity {
            ArrayList<String> listVal = new ArrayList<String>();
            public EditText searchKey;
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                searchKey = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchKey);
                ListView spinner = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                listVal.add("Apple");
                listVal.add("Avocado");
                listVal.add("Banana");
                listVal.add("Blueberry");
                listVal.add("Coconut");
                listVal.add("Durian");
                listVal.add("Guava");
                listVal.add("Kiwifruit");
                listVal.add("Jackfruit");
                ListAdapter listAdapter = new ListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list, listVal);
                spinner.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                spinner.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int pos,
                            long id) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Log.v("listitem_value",values.get(pos));
                        Log.v("EditTextValue",searchKey.getText().toString().trim());
                        Toast.makeText(context, "listitem_value:"+values.get(pos)+"\nEditTextValue:"+searchKey.getText().toString().trim(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }

    }
```

and also remove `implements OnItemClickListener` and `onItemClick` method in `ListAdapter`

Comment: Thanks for reply Tamilan, This works perfect. I tried this type. Is there any way to access edittext outside Activity and inside adapter java file.

Comment: @user2423870 ya it's possible like the same `searchKey.getText().toString().trim()` this will return edit text string.

Comment: That's within the Activity. What if my adapter class is in another file and I am trying to access the EditText?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this also, it may help some others..

```
spinner.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int pos,
                            long id) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        int p = values.get(pos);
                        String key = searchKey.getText().toString().trim();
                        Log.v("listitem_value",p);
                        Log.v("EditTextValue",key);
                        Toast.makeText(context, "listitem_value:"+p+"\nEditTextValue:"+key, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     spinner.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int pos,
                    long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               TextView message = (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.listItem);
               Toast.makeText(context, message.getText().toString(),    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           Log.v("EditText",searchKey.getText().toString().trim());
            }
        });
```